# Acumatica OData Pagination

Tags: pagination, odata, acumatica

At work, we're starting to utilize a BI tool (Birst) that I was tasked with setting up.  One aspect of our data I need to access is our Acumatica data.  I've built several generic inquiries, and can access small ones with no problem, but anything of a decent size just spins and errors out (normally).  I let one attempt run all weekend, so around 60 hours, and it never errored and never loaded data.

I'm assuming it's a network and/or security issue, the server timing out, too much data being sent, or something similar, so I'm looking for a way of accessing large queries.  My first thought was pagination, but as far as I can tell, the pagination options in Acumatica don't work.

Is there any way to do pagination in Acumatica?

As a disclaimer, yes I know the "easy" solution is finding a smaller query, but for some of these that isn't easily possible, and as we're growing isn't a sustainable option as it only spreads the problem over a larger area...so instead of a problem with 1 query I'd eventually have a problem with dozens of them.

Comment: What version of Acumatica are you using? Older versions (5.3 I think) do not support streaming mode and will build a massive document in memory before returning the data.

Comment: As a warning, I'm a db admin and an application developer...my only experience with Acumatica was for this project.

We just switched to a SAS version.  On the main page it says it's:
Acumatica %PRODUCT_VERSION%
Build 1.0.0.0 (DB: 17.204.0019)

If you access the report from a browser, it definitely streams data.  I think the issue is that the Birst side errors out before loading the entire document, and therefore doesn't load any of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is very specific, and works for exporting the data specifically to the BI tool Birst.

I created a query that pulls the max number of records it would process at once (found through experimentation) and used the following query:

```
REPORT_URL?$top=numRows&$orderby=lastModifiedDate asc&$filter=lastModifiedDate ge DateTime'V{maxLoadDate}'&$skip=M[ARRAY]
```

The following variables are Birst context:

- V{maxLoadDate} - a variable that pulls the max of the table it's
  filling.
- M[ARRAY] - an array of variables to pass 1 at a time,
  something like M[0,numRows,numRows*2,numRows*3,...]

As a note, this doesn't make Acumatica export with pagination, however it does effectively paginate it for Birst because it will break the query into a number of separate queries, 1 per object in the array.